# Xcode 4 archive and signing with different certificate for app store submission

Tags: iphone, xcode4, app-store, certificate, archive

In this scenario, we need to submit an app through someone else's account. We don't want to give an xcode project with all the source code, and I doubt he wants to give out his private key so we can build on our machines.

Can Xcode 4 archiving be used to get him a build that he can sign and submit on his end, without compromising the code? It appears the signing happens after the build part of the archive, so my guess is yes but I haven't been able to verify this.

Maybe there's a better way, I'd like to hear that if there is. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Do a build an archive as normal with your certificate, then from Organizer "Share" the Archive. They can then load the archive into their organizer and do a "Share" but this time choose the IPA file, at that point they can choose to resign it with their certificate.

It is suppose to work this way but I have seen instances where Xcode is finicky and it doesn't...